# How to add extra options programatically in multiselect

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, multi-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

How to add extra options programatically? I am using a jquery multiselect [check this](http://loudev.com/)
Already try a solution like this:

```
$('#public-methods').multiSelect('addOption', { value: 42, text: 'test 42', index: 0 });
```

but i get a error message in console like

```
"Method addOption does not exist on jquery.multiSelect"
```

How to solve these problem?

Refe:[check this](http://loudev.com/)

[image]

Comment: In your image it shows the option was added "test 42" ?

Comment: that answer i need but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide a link to the page your working on? When I try to add options to the example multiSelect on the home page of the page you provided using the console I can easily add options and it works fine.

```
$('#aloha').multiSelect('addOption', { value: 'test', 'text': 'wohoo'});
```

Perhaps you can try this in your console on the element your trying to modify?

Comment: cau u send a example program with addoption includins js and css